# Apache proxy: passing on REMOTE_USER to backend server

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy, environment-variables

We are using shibboleth for authentication. Our shibboleth Service provider is running on a host that is running apache with reverse proxy configuration (mod_proxy). The applications using shibboleth are running in the backend, no SP is installed on these servers. We are getting all shibboleth headers on the backend servers.

Now I need the REMOTE_USER variable that is filled by shibboleth authentication on the proxy server to be available on the backend server. I"ve managed to get the value into HTTP_REMOTE_USER and pass it on the the backend servers but i'm struggling to put this value into REMOTE_USER on the backend server.

I would like to know what the difference is between HTTP_REMOTE_USER and REMOTE_USER and how to manipulate REMOTE_USER from the apache config without doing actual authentication.

Comment: What is your remote application running? Is there any reason why you can't run the SP there?

Comment: We like the simplicity of having one SP on the proxy that controls the shib configuration for all the backend applications.

Comment: Are you using Django?  Django adds the "HTTP_".  It isn't really part of the header, it's just a prefix Django adds.

Comment: See : http://serverfault.com/questions/180726/remote-user-through-apache-reverse-proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do exactly the same as you with shibboleth. But unfortunately I found this on the [corresponding apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html). REMOTE_USER is part of the CGI standard therefore cannot be modified with apache directives.

> It is not possible to override or change the standard CGI variables using the environment manipulation directives.

Answer (score 2):

You can send the value of REMOTE_USER on the query string sent to your backend servers:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.*)
RewriteRule ^/test.asp(.*) test.asp?userid=%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} [QSA,P,L]
```

The LA-U means lookahead.  From the [mod_rewrite manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> %{LA-U:variable} can be used for look-aheads which perform an internal (URL-based) sub-request to determine the final value of variable. This can be used to access variable for rewriting which is not available at the current stage, but will be set in a later phase.
>
> For instance, to rewrite according to the REMOTE_USER variable from within the per-server context (httpd.conf file) you must use %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} - this variable is set by the authorization phases, which come after the URL translation phase (during which mod_rewrite operates).