# REMOTE_USER = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN under x509 with +FakeBasicAuth in Apache. Is it possible?

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, environment-variables, mod-ssl, x509

Hi I'm trying to incorporate a software to our intranet services (BackupPc)

This Software uses the environment variable `REMOTE_USER` to get the username. Placed under an Apache 2.2 server with Client certificate Authentication system and `FakeBasicAuth` enabled, `REMOTE_USER` gets the same value as `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN`, which have all the distinguished name string of the certificate.

I'm trying to set `REMOTE_USER` the contents of `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN` which has a content which matches with my usernames and easyer and shorter to read.

This environment variable passed to CGI can not be changed by `SetEnv` and `SetEnfIf`. There's also a mod_ssl directive, `SSLUserName` but the [Apache 2.2 official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslusername) says that it won't work with FakeBasicAuth enabled.

So I'm wondering if I'm missing something or there's a clever workarround on this issue.

I can't drop FakeBasicAuth because that's our authmodel on the rest of the intranet, And I dont want to patch the code of the application (I did it to get it working but I want to drop the patched code in favor of the official one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It seems](https://serverfault.com/questions/23273/apache-proxy-passing-on-remote-user-to-backend-server/27576#27576) that `REMOTE_USER` cannot be modified by apache directives, so what about modifying BackupPc to use `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN` variable or to set the value of `REMOTE_USER` in its startup code?

Comment: I Already did it to get it working. I'ts just a one line patch of perl code which adds this feature to BackuPc. But now I need to manatain the patched code for my system on each upgrade of BackupPc, And that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: That wasn't an answer, but the answer is that there's no answer.